# How to avoid using mysql_fetch_assoc twice

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

Current page uses the:

```
$row_rsMyData = mysql_fetch_assoc (rsMyData);
```

As part of the mysql query created by Dreamweaver.

Later on in the page I'm using:

```
while ($row_rsMyData = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsMyData))
```

To fetch filenames from the database to add to an array.

The problem is the first fetch gets the first records in the row and doesn't leave the data there for the second fetch meaning the result is an array with one record missing.

What could I use instead of the second fetch or is there a way to reset before the second one takes place.

I have tried

```
mysql_data_seek()
```

But it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

The statement:

```
  $row_rsMyData = mysql_fetch_assoc (rsMyData);
```

does not reference an array-type variable. To gather multiple values into an array instead use:

```
  $row_rsMyData[] = mysql_fetch_assoc (rsMyData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that you should not be using `mysql_*` functions, you can just check the current value of `$row_rsMyData` in the loop condition, use those data, and then fetch the next row at the end of the loop:

```
while($row_rsMyData)
{
    //do stuff with the data in $row_rsMyData

    //fetch the next row
    $row_rsMyData = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsMyData);
}
```

This of course assumes you can't do anything about removing the line generated by Dreamweaver.